# Cutting up large XML file into small chunks

Tags: xml, vb.net, wikipedia

I have a large wikipedia dump that I want to cut into different files (1 file for each article). I wrote a VB App to do it for me, but it was quite slow and crapped out after a few hours of cutting. Im currently splitting the file into smaller 50mb chunks using another app but thats taking a long time (20-30 minutes for each chunk). I should be able to cut each of these up individually if I do this.

Does anyone have any suggestions of a way to cut this file up quicker?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this with C# is with an XmlReader.  You can stay with the XmlReader alone for the fastest implementation or combine with the new LINQ XNode classes for a decent combination of performance and ease of use.  See this MSDN article for an example:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.readfrom.aspx.

You should be able to modify the example to only hold the node for one document in memory at a time and then write it back out as a file.  It should perform well and work for very large files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're using the DOM parser. For potentially large files you should always use [SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) parsers. DOM parsers read the entire file into memory, SAX parsers read as little as possible at a time, and therefore operate much more efficiently. [This tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_data/xml/article.php/c4221) describes how to write a C# SAX parser, VB should be very similar.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this in Java, I'd use [javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html) and [javax.xml.stream.XMLEventWriter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventWriter.html).

In some sort of pseudocode, let's assume an `<article>` tag delimits each wikipedia article, that you don't need to worry about nested `<article>` tags, and you have an `openNewWriter()` function to open a new `XMLEventWriter` that writes to a new file with a suitable name for this article.

Then my code would look like something like this:

```
XMLEventReader r = // an XMLEventReader for the original wikipedia dump

XMLEventWriter w = null;

bool isInsideArticle = false;

while (r.hasNext()){
  XMLEvent e = r.nextEvent();

  if (e.isStartElement() &&
        e.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart().equals("article")){
     w = openNewWriter();
     // write the stuff that belongs outside the <article> tag
     // by synthesizing XMLEvents and using w.add() to add them
     w.add(e);
     isInsideArticle = true;
  } else if (e.isEndElement() &&
           e.asEndElement().getName().getLocalPart().equals("article")) {
     w.add(e);
     // write the stuff that belongs outside the <article> tag
     // by synthesizing XMLEvents and using w.add() to add them
     isInsideArticle = false;
     w.close();
  } else if (isInsideArticle) {
     w.add(e);
  } else {
     // this tag gets dropped on the floor because it's not inside any article
  }
}
```

Now all you need to do is find the streaming XML classes in .NET. I think they're [system.xml.XMLReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) and [system.xml.XMLWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx), but my expertise isn't in .NET, and I can't tell from the documentation whether they'll work quite same way as the Java version I just gave you.

(My purpose here is more to show you how to approach the problem than to tell you the names of the classes you need.)

Answer (score -1):

You should try vtd-xml for that, we have got people telling us how well it works for splitting large XML files... http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/xml_processing_future.aspx
we were also told that DOM takes forever